# ASP.NET Async issues

Tags: asp.net, json, http, asynchronous, post

The following code attempts to make a POST request from Program.cs, however I am getting an error stating that "await operator can only be within an async method". What code would fix this?

```
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        BuildWebHost(args).Run();

        string myJson = "{'Username': 'myusername','Password':'pass'}";
        using (var client = new HttpClient())
        {
            var response = await client.PostAsync(
                "https://example.com",
                 new StringContent(myJson, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json"));
        }

    }
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make your Main method async or put this code in some other async method and call it from Main method.
As the error message shows, if you have to use `await` keyword, then the method which contains that keyword should be asynchronous one. Refer:https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/async-and-await-in-c-sharp/